# Programming introduction book

Tags: programming-languages

I've offered an out-of-job girl to help her study programming (with an MCSD as the ultimate goal) - and she has no progrmming knowledge. The idea is that she'll study from books and I"ll help.

Help- I need a gentle introduction to programming book, very easy, very practical, very hands-on and up to date. Optimally would be for the .Net 4.0 MS enviornment (C#,Visual Basic) but other alternaitves (Jave, Python etc.) are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Head First C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514824) is a good start.

It is C# 3.0 and uses VS 2008, though all examples should work with VS 2010 and C# 4.0.

Update:

Looks like is [has been updated](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfcsharp/) to C# 4.0 and VS 2010.

Comment: Hi Oded. 71K rep - Kavod! Know that book, and I think I"ll adapt your suggestion and use "Head First Programming: A Learner's Guide to Programming Using the Python Language" (even though I don't know python) because it seems more beginner oriented.

Comment: @Avi - Toda. Python is considered a good beginners language, so not a bad choice. I suggested the C# book since you said the .NET 4.0 is what you would optimally want ;)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from books MSDN is also a great resource though. For C# for example more information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/vcsharp/aa336768.aspx). It's specifically for people which are new to development, this can be an alternative resource.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Looked there, didn't seem appropriate for complete novices.